# If my Android project only has v21 layouts, will it support older devices?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout, material-design

Say I have the following layout resources files in my Android project:

```
activity_create_group.xml (v21)
activity_create_group.xml (large-v21)
activity_create_group.xml (small-v21)
activity_create_group.xml (xlarge-v21)
activity_create_group.xml (xlarge-land-v21)
```

Does this mean that devices below API 21 will crash? Or will this file support older devices anyway, by removing certain API-specific features such as `android:elevation="4dp"` (v21) and `android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"` (v16) automatically?

What's the verdict on this?

If I have those additional features, and also want to support older OS' should I also include:

```
activity_create_group.xml (v16)
activity_create_group.xml (large-v16)
activity_create_group.xml (small-v16)
activity_create_group.xml (xlarge-v16)
activity_create_group.xml (xlarge-land-v16)
```

...and:

```
activity_create_group.xml
activity_create_group.xml (large)
activity_create_group.xml (small)
activity_create_group.xml (xlarge)
activity_create_group.xml (xlarge-land)
```

Seems overkill. Also, lots of tedious copy-paste. Are there common batch scripts for generating layout files in this way? Does Android Studio handle this? What does the UI team at an Android development studio, for example, do to handle all these resource files?

When downgrading I typically have to change several features, such as changing the following:

```
android:paddingEnd="10dp"
android:paddingStart="25dp"
```

...to:

```
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="25dp"
android:paddingEnd="10dp"
android:paddingStart="25dp"
```

If I really want to support every device and every API-specific feature, you're looking at maintaining 15 layout files for each Activity. I just can't accept this, but given that I've never worked at an agency that would presumably be very anal about this, I'm not sure where to find this kind of information.

In summary, my question is the first one... **Which devices will not be supported if I only supply the v21 layout files provided above?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as UI dimensions are not affected and your additional style changes like elevation is not a thing to worry about, then you can safely continue to write a single layout file without categorizing them based on the API.

IDE warns you about the API so that you can use alternates for that API, for example using 9 patch shadow to create elevation effect in lower APIs, but if your app can work without these additional **design luxuries** then its always recommended to use single default layout file.

And for the point of `paddingStart` & `paddingLeft` and `marginStart` & `marginLeft` there is no harm in including both the attributes in single xml instead of creating two xmls with relevant attributes.

Comment: Okay so even if I include those design luxuries in a layout file that isn't categorized according to API, this will not cause interference on devices that can't handle them? That these are merely warnings to the developer is what I'm trying to confirm. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to test them with android virtual device emulator,create a virtual device ,for example nexus 4 with ice cream sandwich and debbug the application to it.

Comment: If only I had virtualization on this old hunkin' Lenovo ;P

Comment: Intel Core i5-6300 CPU @ 2.40 GHz  64-bit Windows 7 12.0 GB RAM

Comment: @santafebound you can try enabling virtualisation while bootup and later install intel haxm from SDK manager. Steps for former are available on google.

Comment: your lenovo is capable for virtualization @santafebound ,enable virtualization in bios just as Mohammed suggested